# Application Insights through proxy

Tags: c#, .net, proxy

I need to implement the Application Application via a proxy.

```
      var config = new TelemetryConfiguration
      {
        InstrumentationKey = "key",
        TelemetryChannel = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.InMemoryChannel()
      };
      var client = new TelemetryClient(config);
```

There is an WPF application on my PC (firewall enabled) that communicates with some server and I only need to proxy all the AppInsights requests, and the rest do not.

I could at every AppInsights request set a proxy and at the end clean it, but communication with the server goes on constantly, and at the time of AppInsigns request can occur and "normal" request, which does not need to be proxied.

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy("myproxy"); //so does not fit (that's bs)
_telemetry.TrackEvent(key, properties, metrics);
Flush();
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
```

How can I solve this situation? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
          var config = new TelemetryConfiguration
          {
            InstrumentationKey = "key",
            TelemetryChannel = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.InMemoryChannel()
          };
          config.TelemetryChannel.EndpointAddress = "https://myproxy.proxy";
          var client = new TelemetryClient(config);
```

And your proxy must redirect traffic to `https://dc.services.visualstudio.com:443/v2/track`